# python median based on aggregation and current record exclusion

Tags: python, lambda, group-by

I would like to add a new column which reflects a computed median based on value1 grouping on the key value but which excludes each record itself from the median calc.

Below is an example of the data with what my desired output should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'key': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'value1': [0.1, 0.244, 0.373, 0.514, 0.663, 0.786, 0.902, 1.01, 1.151, 1.295, 1.434, 1.541, 1.679, 1.793, 1.94, 2.049, 2.164, 2.284, 2.432, 2.533, 2.68, 2.786, 2.906, 3.008, 3.136], 'value2': ['Dept1', 'Dept2', 'Dept3', 'Dept4', 'Dept5', 'Dept6', 'Dept7', 'Dept8', 'Dept9', 'Dept10', 'Dept11', 'Dept12', 'Dept13', 'Dept14', 'Dept15', 'Dept16', 'Dept17', 'Dept18', 'Dept19', 'Dept20', 'Dept21', 'Dept22', 'Dept23', 'Dept24', 'Dept25'], 'desired_output':['0.589', '0.589', '0.589', '0.518', '0.444', '0.444', '0.444', '1.61', '1.61', '1.61', '1.61', '1.557', '1.488', '1.488', '1.488', '1.488', '2.733', '2.733', '2.733', '2.733', '2.66', '2.607', '2.607', '2.607', '2.607'] })
```

I have tried this code which returns an error of "Transform function invalid for data types":

```py
df['desired_output2'] = df.groupby(['key'], as_index = False)['value1'].transform(lambda x: [x[(v['value2'] != x['value2'])].median() for v in x])
```

I think a groupby with looping lambda should work for this but can't get the syntax right.

Comment: Please share your data and code in a format that allows people to copy and test it.

Comment: I thought I did that.  If you can clarify what I did wrong, I will be sure to improve next time I enter a question.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["value3"] = df.groupby("key")["value1"].transform(
    lambda x: [x[x.index != i].median() for i in x.index]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   key  value1  value2 desired_output  value3
0    A   0.100   Dept1          0.589  0.5885
1    A   0.244   Dept2          0.589  0.5885
2    A   0.373   Dept3          0.589  0.5885
3    A   0.514   Dept4          0.518  0.5180
4    A   0.663   Dept5          0.444  0.4435
5    A   0.786   Dept6          0.444  0.4435
6    A   0.902   Dept7          0.444  0.4435
7    B   1.010   Dept8           1.61  1.6100
8    B   1.151   Dept9           1.61  1.6100
9    B   1.295  Dept10           1.61  1.6100
10   B   1.434  Dept11           1.61  1.6100
11   B   1.541  Dept12          1.557  1.5565
12   B   1.679  Dept13          1.488  1.4875
13   B   1.793  Dept14          1.488  1.4875
14   B   1.940  Dept15          1.488  1.4875
15   B   2.049  Dept16          1.488  1.4875
16   C   2.164  Dept17          2.733  2.7330
17   C   2.284  Dept18          2.733  2.7330
18   C   2.432  Dept19          2.733  2.7330
19   C   2.533  Dept20          2.733  2.7330
20   C   2.680  Dept21           2.66  2.6595
21   C   2.786  Dept22          2.607  2.6065
22   C   2.906  Dept23          2.607  2.6065
23   C   3.008  Dept24          2.607  2.6065
24   C   3.136  Dept25          2.607  2.6065
```